# How to sort a List of SelecListItem by group name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sorting

I'm trying to sort a list of SelectListItems by the group name. I am able to apply groups and sort based on the group, but I can't seem to change which group appears first. The group "B" is always displayed before group "A" even when sorting by group name.

```
List<SelectListItem> locationList = new List<SelectListItem>(dynamicTypes.Where(p => p.DynamicTypeId == DynamicTypes.Areas && p.ParentTypeId != null).Select(p => new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = p.NameEnglish,
            Value = p.Id.ToString()
        }));
SelectListGroup groupA = new SelectListGroup();
groupA.Name = "A";
SelectListGroup groupB = new SelectListGroup();
groupB.Name = "B";
foreach(SelectListItem sel in locationList)
{
    if (sel.Text == "Aylmer, east of Vanier" || sel.Text == "Aylmer, west of Vanier" || sel.Text == "Gatineau, east of Paiement" || sel.Text == "Gatineau, west of Paiement"
        || sel.Text == "Hull" || sel.Text == "Parc de la Montagne" || sel.Text == "Plateau")
    {
        sel.Group = groupA;
    }
    else
    {
        sel.Group = groupB;
    }
}

locationList.OrderBy(p => p.Group.Name);
```

Comment: Please show where you define and populate `locationList`

Comment: `locationList = locationList.OrderBy(p => p.Group.Name);` May need at the end ToList or ToArray.

Comment: `locationList = locationList.OrderBy(p => p.Group.Name);` (you have to assign it after sorting).

Comment: Stephen Muecke and Gusman, thanks. Working now with locationList = locationList.OrderBy(p => p.Group.Name).ToList();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`OrderBy` doesn't sort in place, it creates a new list as the return value so you need to assign it to a variable to be able to use it:

```
locationList = locationList.OrderBy(p => p.Group.Name);
```

Here the original `locationList` will be overwritten by the sorted list. If you need the original list use a new variable:

```
var sortedList = locationList.OrderBy(p => p.Group.Name);
```

Answer (score 0):

To sort in place use the Sort method:

```
locationList.Sort((x, y) => x.Text.CompareTo(y.Text));
```